# how can I pass a function into another function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have a function that check Username in a form,parent function i check if there are empty field, and now i wanna pass usernameValidat() in inside onSubmit() to check if it match with my username validation. Can anyone give me the answer to solve this issue please

```
onSubmit() {
            var text = "Please insert ";
            for (let i = 0; i < Constant.REGISTER_INFOS.length; i++) {
                if (Constant.REGISTER_INFOS[i].info == "") {
                    text = text + Constant.REGISTER_INFOS[i].title.toLowerCase() + ", ";
                }
            }
            alert(text);
            
        },
        usernameValidate() {
            if (Constant.REGISTER_INFOS[0].info.length < 4) {
                alert("Username is too short");
                return false;
            }
        },
```

Comment: `usernameValidate` is not a pure function - it has side-effects, so you cannot compose it the way you want to.

Comment: Why is it called `Constant` (in `Constant.REGISTER_INFOS[0].info.length`) if it's **mutable**?

Comment: @Dai can you explain more, I have no idea

Comment: @Dai yes, i set Constant in a constant.js file

Comment: It sounds like you're new to both JavaScript and programming in general... so getting started with VueJS at this point is likely a bad idea as you're trying to run before you know how to walk...  so let me ask you: what is your current level-of-understanding of FP? and concepts like mutability, pure-functions, idempotence, idempotence, etc?

Comment: @Dai yes, it so true, Programming is not my major in Uni and i just want to change my career path

Comment: Is this part of a VueJS, `methods: {}` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this is part of a Vue app, so something like:

```
const App = new Vue({
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      var text = "Please insert ";
      for (let i = 0; i < Constant.REGISTER_INFOS.length; i++) {
        if (Constant.REGISTER_INFOS[i].info == "") {
          text = text + Constant.REGISTER_INFOS[i].title.toLowerCase() + ", ";
        }
      }
      alert(text);
    },
    usernameValidate() {
      if (Constant.REGISTER_INFOS[0].info.length < 4) {
        alert("Username is too short");
        return false;
      }
    },
  }
});
```

Then you want to call another method using the `this` keyword, to access other methods on this Vue instance.

So `onSubmit()` might look like:

```
    onSubmit() {
      var text = "Please insert ";
      for (let i = 0; i < Constant.REGISTER_INFOS.length; i++) {
        if (Constant.REGISTER_INFOS[i].info == "") {
          text = text + Constant.REGISTER_INFOS[i].title.toLowerCase() + ", ";
        }
      }
      this.usernameValidate();
      alert(text);
    },
```

There are some big issues with this code though, and that won't actually do anything of note, as nothing is being done with the return value.

A better way to handle this would be to:

1. Return true or false from `usernameValidate`, depending on whether or not it's successful, and check it in `if` statement.
2. Change the *signature* of the `usernameValidate` method to take an `argument`. This means that we can re-use this functionality with any input, making it a lot more flexible.

With these two changes, we end up with the following:

```
const App = new Vue({
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      var text = "Please insert ";
      for (let i = 0; i < Constant.REGISTER_INFOS.length; i++) {
        if (Constant.REGISTER_INFOS[i].info == "") {
          text = text + Constant.REGISTER_INFOS[i].title.toLowerCase() + ", ";
        }
      }
      if (this.usernameValidate(Constant.REGISTER_INFOS[0].info) {
        alert(text);
        return true;
      }
      alert("Registration Failed!");
      return false;
    },
    usernameValidate(username) {
      if (username.length < 4) {
        alert("Username is too short");
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    },
  }
});
```

Hopefully that clears a few things up, and can give you a little more insight in to programming in general.

Having said all of that, I would highly recommend learning JavaScript from scratch, before getting stuck in to frameworks (which VueJS is) and things like that. Understanding the core principles of programming, conditional logic, etc., will make you much more competent in the long run, and just grabbing at code snippets from StackOverflow will just lead to you pulling your hair out, and being stuck on a problem for days at a time.

Comment: It work,i will do as your suggest, it's so hard at the beginning but i will take it seriously as much as possible

Comment: That's fine, it'll take a while, but sooner or later it'll all start to click, and I'm sure you'll get there. :)

Comment: I appreciate that <333